# Reducing space between li elements

Tags: html, css, element

How to reduce the space between li horizontal elements in my code, I've been trying to do it by changing padding and margin attributes (I have already tried setting those attributes to negative values, but it didn't help).

Below is the code that I'm trying

```
  footer li {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 300px;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding-right: 70px;
  list-style: none;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please edit your question to include the HTML also, as this is what the CSS is being applied to. Also include details of what you have already tried (so we don't suggest them to you again). See how to create a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can see the problem in action and be able to figure out what is going wrong.

Comment: Try `line-height`?

Comment: Please show your HTML Code or screenshot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Justify the parent of the list (not the list) to start and that gives you control over the list - the lists will now be flexibles of a flexed parent - you should be able to whatever you want with the lists if you follow this guide

1. First of all, the line "display:flex" has changed the display - so you are really not working with a normal list any more.
2. Secondly I can see you set "justify-content: space-around;" that has limited the ability of "margin" in your code;
3. Change "space-around" to "flex-start" and add margin as desired, or let "space-around" do its work

Comment: So I tried to change justify-content property to start, didn't do much, so question remains maybe you know any other tricks that could help me to solve this problem. As I said earlier changing the margin only moves whole list it does not reduce the space between li elements.

Comment: Justify the parent of the list (not the list) to start and that gives you control over the list - the lists will now be flexibles of a flexed parent

Answer (score 0):

So here is the answer, maybe it will be of any help to those who don't know how to close the gap between li elements. Just add this property to your code and it will help you to reduce the space between elements. `footer li:not(:first-of-type) { margin-left: -25px; }`   Problem solved and I would like to thank everyone for the help.